# How should I tag a question for a game that doesn't already have a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just posted a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132326/is-this-evacuation-level-even-solvable) about a game that doesn't have a tag for it already.  (So I tagged it with something that doesn't really apply.)

How do I tag it correctly, since I don't have the reputation necessary to make a new tag?

(I searched on meta with all the terms I could think of, but couldn't find an answer.)

Comment: For the love of god, this needs to be in the FAQ.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, I agree, which is why I was quite surprised I couldn't find an answer either in help or on meta.

Comment: you didn't look hard enough on Meta. Clearly.

Comment: See also: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/813/i-want-to-ask-a-question-about-a-game-which-has-no-tag-yet-how-should-i-tag-it?rq=1 and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7688/is-there-a-tag-less-tag and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7665/should-a-gta-5-tag-be-made-ready and and and and and and

Comment: (Do note, I'm not angry at you, but rather our own poor housekeeping for not properly handling all of these dupes in the first place.)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, I figured as much.  What surprises me is that all my searching didn't lead me to any of the answers on here.  If I, an experience SE user, didn't find an answer, how many newbies would have the same problem, yet not know to ask on meta?

Answer (score 2):

Do your best, and flag (or leave a comment!) explaining the situation.

A high-rep user or mod will usually be along to assist you in short order.

In your case, I've already added [evacuation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evacuation) for you! Hooray!